# Newly added column in 'j' of data.table should be available in the scope

Tags: r, data.table

I have this code:

```
dat<-dat[,list(colA,colB
                     ,RelativeIncome=Income/.SD[Nation=="America",Income]
                     ,RelativeIncomeLog2=log2(Income)-log2(.SD[Nation=="America",Income])) #Read 1)
               ,by=list(Name,Nation)]
```

1) I would like to be able to say `"RelativeIncomeLog2=log2(RelativeIncome)"`, but  `"RelativeIncome"` is not available in `j`'s scope?

2) I tried the following instead (per the data.table FAQ). Now `"RelativeIncome"` is available but it doesn't add the columns:

```
     dat<-dat[,{colA;colB;RelativeIncome=Income/.SD[Nation=="America",Income];
               ,RelativeIncomeLog2=log2(RelativeIncome)])) 
               ,by=list(Name,Nation)]
```

Comment: Ricardo's answer probably clarifies this, but the function `J()` is not the same as the `j` argument to `[.data.table`. Try ``?J`` and ``?`[.data.table` `` for details. `J()` is for joins in the `i` argument of `[.data.table`.

Comment: See also [How can I evaluate (or create) an on the fly column in data.table in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712858/how-can-i-evaluate-or-create-an-on-the-fly-column-in-data-table-in-r)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create and assign objects in `j`, just use `{` curly braces `}`.

You can then pass these objects (or functions & calculations of the objects) out of `j` and assign them as columns of the data.table.  To assign more than once column at a time, simply:

- wrap the `LHS` in `c(.)` *make sure column names are strings* and
- the last line of `j` (*ie, the "return" value*) should be a list.

---

```
  dat[ , c("NewIncomeComlumn", "AnotherNewColumn") := { 
                 RelativeIncome     <- Income/.SD[Nation == "A", Income];   
                 RelativeIncomeLog2 <- log2(RelativeIncome);  
                 ## this last line is what will be asigned.
                 list(RelativeIncomeLog2 * 100,  c("A", "hello", "World"))
                 # assigned values are recycled as needed.
                 # If the recycling does not match up, a warning is issued. 
                }
                , by = list(Name, Nation)
               ]
```

---

You can losely think of `j` as a function within the environment of `dat`

You can also get a lot more sophisticated and complex if required.  You can also incorporate `by` arguments as well, using   `by=list(<someName>=col)`

In fact, similar to functions, simply creating an object in `j` and assigning it a value, *does not* mean that it will be available outside of `j`.  In order for it to be assigned to your data.table, you must return it.  `j` automatically returns the last line; if that last line is a list, each element of the list will be handled as a column.  If you are assigning by reference (ie, using `:=` ) then you will achieve the results you are expecting.

---

On a separate note, I noticed the following in your code:

```
 Income / .SD[Nation == "America", Income]

 # Which instead could simply be: 
 Income / Income[Nation == "America"]
```

`.SD` is great in that it is a wonderful shorthand.  However, to invoke it without needing all of the columns which it encapsulates is to burden your code with extra memory costs. If you are using only a single column, consider naming that column explicitly or perhaps add the `.SDcols` argument (after `j`) and being naming the columns needed there.

Comment: maybe a silly question.. but what in your example only "RelativeIncomeLog2*100" will get assigned to a NewIncomeColumn. But what if I want 2 new columns corresponding to "RelativeIncome" and "RelativeIncomeLog2*100"?

Comment: @varuman, not a silly question.  The short answer is to wrap the final line in `list(.)`  See the edit above for details.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I think it's a mistake to have `by = ...` within the ending `}`? Shouldn't it come after the `list(.)` statement?

Comment: Thanks for catching my oversight Arun. Edited & fixed