# Can I use variables newly created in `j` in the same `j` argument?

Tags: r, data.table

In the `j` argument in `data.table`, is there syntax allowing me to reference previously created variables while in the same `j` statement? I'm thinking of something like Lisp's `let*` construct.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(22)
DT <- data.table(a = rep(1:5, each = 10),
                 b = sample(c(0,1), 50, rep = TRUE))

DT[ ,
   list(attempts = .N,
        successes = sum(b),
        rate = successes / attempts),
   by = a]
```

This results in

```
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , list(attempts = .N, successes = sum(b),  : 
#  object 'successes' not found
```

I understand why, but is there a different way to accomplish this in the same `j`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newly added column in 'j' of data.table should be available in the scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510915/newly-added-column-in-j-of-data-table-should-be-available-in-the-scope)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- Itself a duplicate of this one: [How can I evaluate (or create) an on the fly column in data.table in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712858/how-can-i-evaluate-or-create-an-on-the-fly-column-in-data-table-in-r/15713753#comment22337886_15713753) ;) Seems to be a common wish among data.table for users.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien,  that's great! Maybe we can merge them all?   Nice observation though. Perhaps we should put something in the DT FAQ about this

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- Possibly, though mostly I find it odd that people think it *should* work like that. After all, neither of these works either, for essentially the same reason: `list(a=1:4, b=2*a)` and `data.frame(a=1:4, b=2*a)`. So why should it be any different with `data.table`?!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, because `data.table` is pure wizardry!   Truthfully, the real reason I think people _expect_ it to work is because they are modifying an object from within the object. So it's almost becomes an expected quality.  I certainly agree with you as far as your analogy

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- Hah! The wizardry thing was my best guess as well ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
DT[ , {
    list(attempts = attempts <- .N,
         successes = successes <- sum(b),
         rate = successes/attempts)
    },  by = a]
#    a attempts successes rate
# 1: 1       10         5  0.5
# 2: 2       10         6  0.6
# 3: 3       10         3  0.3
# 4: 4       10         5  0.5
# 5: 5       10         5  0.5
```

FWIW, [this closely related **data.table** feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/659) would make possible +/- the syntax used in your question. Quoting from the linked page:

> **Summary:**
>
> Iterative RHS of `:=` (and `` `:=`(...) ``), and multiple `:=` inside `j = {...}` syntax
>
> **Detailed description**
>
> e.g. `` DT[, `:=`( m1 = mean(a), m2 = sd(a), s = m1/m2 ), by = group] ``
>
> where s can use previous lhs names ( using the word 'iterative' tries to convey that ).

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
DT[,
   {successes = sum(b);
    attempts  = .N;
    list(attempts = attempts,
         successes = successes,
         rate = successes / attempts)
   },
   by = a]
```

or

```
DT[,
   list(attempts = .N,
        successes = sum(b)),
   by = a][, rate := successes / attempts]
```