# chaining in data.table to compute row sum

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a transformed data.table like this:

```
name <- c("Bob","Mary","Jane","Kim")
weight <- c(60,65,45,55)
height <- c(170,165,140,135)
dft <- data.table(name,weight,height) 
dft <-  data.table (dft[,.(name)] ,     dft[, weight %*% t(weight)]) 
names(dft) <- c("name", str_c("tau",1:4))
```

Now I first multiply `tau12 = tau1 * tau2` and compute the row sums across all the five columns, including `tau12`.

If I use

```
dft[,  `:=`(tau12 = tau1 * tau2, 
            sum1 = lapply(.SD, sum) ) , .SDcols = patterns("^tau")  ]
```

However, `sum1` only computes the sum of four columns, not including the column `tau12`.

I wonder how to compute the sum `tau1+tau2+tau3+tau4+tau12` in this case? This is different from what `dplyr::mutate` does, where the newly generated variables can be involved in subsequent operations.

Comment: You can refer to newly created variables in an anonymous body (`{...}`). See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898349)

Comment: I figured out an alternative way. Replace ```=``` with ```<-``` for those temporary new variables.

Comment: Yes, that's also a possibility ([How can I evaluate (or create) an on the fly column in data.table in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712858/how-can-i-evaluate-or-create-an-on-the-fly-column-in-data-table-in-r)). I tend to prefer the `{...}` for more complex expressions though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
> dft[, tau12 := tau1 * tau2][, .(rowS = rowSums(.SD)), name, .SDcols = patterns("^tau")]       
   name     rowS
1:  Bob 14053500
2: Mary 16492125
3: Jane  7907625
4:  Kim 11809875
```